# Axios 0.19.2 not sending CSRF token with

Tags: laravel, axios, csrf-token

I have a problem with my Laravel application, after pushing local changes to the master branch and then pulling master from the Linux server, I get a CSRF token mismatch whenever I do an axios request.

This issue is not present in the local environment which uses PHP artisan serve, but the Linux server uses apache2.

I have tried clearing cookies, I have tried incognito windows I have tried on another computer, I have updated axios to 0.19.2 I have cleared all errors with dependencies missing and I cannot get rid of this error.

When I inspect the network tab I see that the request header does not contain XSRF-thing-a-ma-jig and as far as I know axios includes it automatically. Also, on the local environment it is included and visible.

Here is how I make the axios request

```
                    axios.delete(`/${objectType.toLowerCase()}/${objectId}`)
                    .then((returnData) => {
                        this.getPosts(); // to be replaced
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

and here are the two rows for axios in bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Obviously I have the csrf_token meta tag in the head of the page.

I am at a loss, I can't test the old version from git since it throws a 500 server error, I guess I broke something somewhere along the lines but the same master branch is working on the local environment so it should work on the Linux server...

I need help !

UPDATE: I think I found a possible reason, the cookies tab shows the same XSRF-Token all the time, even after multiple times deleting the cookies in browser, also on other computers as well. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: can u check your master blade have csrf token include in head ?

Comment: @kamlesh as mentioned in the ticket I have csrftoken meta tag on for every page

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: No idea I guess I have :/ can't remember at this point